# WSHttpBinding and Https problem

Tags: .net, wcf, app-config, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I want to use Sessions and SSL at the same time so I set up all the certificates and made sure everything was set up properly on the WCF service. I've tried about everything but I cant seem to get this to work. It throws me a InvalidoperationException saying that the WsHttpBinding can't create secure sessions and that I should use MessageSecurity instead of TransportSecurity.But I want to use Https and not Http so I want to use TransportSecurity. Could Anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

App.config for WsHttpBinding:

```
   <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding">
     <reliableSession enabled="True" />
     <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
     </security>
    </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that the InvalidOperationException Occurs when I try to call ServiceHost.Open() So the Logging will not do much good, but thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try it but [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735116.aspx):

> To use a reliable session over HTTPS, you must create a custom binding that uses a reliable session and the HTTPS transport.

Try the custom binding described in the article.

Edit:

I checked with Reflector why it doesn't work with `WsHttpBinding`. `WsHttpBinding` contains this code when initializing security:

```
if (isReliableSession && !this.IsSecureConversationEnabled())
{
    throw ...
}
```

It probably means that `WsHttpBinding` allows using reliable session over unsecured channel or over channel secured with message security and secure conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you enable [WCF logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) and take a look at the resulting logfile using [SvcTraceViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx). This should provide you with a lot more detail about what's going on and usually helps me in tracking down the more difficult WCF issues.